# what is DDMServer and why is it allocating so many objects?

Tags: android

I'm optimizing my game because I see GC's which cause stutters in my game :

> 11-26 15:20:14.881 27534-27542/my.game.android W/art: Suspending all
>   threads took: 11.505ms 11-26 15:24:53.042 27534-27542/my.game.android
>   W/art: Suspending all threads took: 8.758ms 11-26 15:25:13.602
>   27534-27542/my.game.android W/art: Suspending all threads took:
>   21.606ms 11-26 15:26:49.836 27534-27542/my.game.android W/art: Suspending all threads took: 10.009ms 11-26 15:28:08.533
>   27534-27542/my.game.android W/art: Suspending all threads took:
>   7.598ms 11-26 15:28:11.556 27534-27542/my.game.android W/art: Suspending all threads took: 6.225ms 11-26 15:28:18.062
>   27534-27542/my.game.android W/art: Suspending all threads took:
>   5.645ms 11-26 15:28:36.620 27534-27542/my.game.android W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.401ms 11-26 15:28:41.625
>   27534-27542/my.game.android W/art: Suspending all threads took:
>   5.859ms 11-26 15:29:14.207 27534-27542/my.game.android W/art: Suspending all threads took: 6.469ms 11-26 15:29:29.262
>   27534-27542/my.game.android W/art: Suspending all threads took:
>   7.720ms 11-26 15:29:58.820 27534-27542/my.game.android W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.218ms 11-26 15:30:46.457
>   27534-27542/my.game.android W/art: Suspending all threads took:
>   18.218ms 11-26 15:32:05.124 27534-27542/my.game.android W/art: Suspending all threads took: 12.481ms 11-26 15:33:32.829
>   27534-27542/my.game.android W/art: Suspending all threads took:
>   7.629ms 11-26 15:34:36.461 27534-27542/my.game.android W/art: Suspending all threads took: 7.324ms 11-26 15:34:45.000
>   27534-27542/my.game.android W/art: Suspending all threads took:
>   14.831ms 11-26 15:35:04.028 27534-27542/my.game.android W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.065ms

100% of these are triggered by DDMServer :

[image]

What can I do about it - if anything ?
If I create a release build, will the same GC's trigger ?

---

**EDIT:**

In the image below, what is "Thread 3" ? The image shows all the threads in my game, but how do I associate one of the named threads to "Thread 3" ?

[image]

Comment: Me too.  I am seeing exactly this.  My app is very gradually consuming heap whilst sitting doing nothing. Update:- Should only happen in debug, not release (DDM - Dalvik Debug Monitor http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/2.0/dalvik/docs/debugmon.html)

Comment: cool thanks :-) saves me having to start a bounty on this. I'm surprised nobody else knew about this, or apparently has encountered this. I suppose not many people look at the memory side of things...